# jquery .html load html into div form tab key not working

Tags: jquery, forms, html, tabs

I am loading a dynamic html form with javascript into a div using jquery().html(), which inserts, and displays the form perfectly. The javascript executes as well. The problem I am having is that on the form, the tab key does not work. There are tabindex= values set for each

Any ideas on why the tab key may not be working? I've tried FF, IE, Chrome and Safari and they all have the same tab key issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To add, I'm just adding the entire html, javascript and all with $('#'+div).html(htmlcontent);.

Comment: When you say you're adding "JavaScript and all", are you talking about inline event attributes, or...? I take it the `tabindex` values are positive numbers? Perhaps you could show some of the code or provide a demo at http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

You must be doing something wrong in your code. (Maybe you're highjacking the tab keypress event?)  I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLxA6/) and it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with all browsers that I used.

1. Press F12 into your  Google Chrome (dev console).
2. Open your application form
3. Into developer console, open "Console" tab and enter the code bellow:

```js
setInterval(function() {console.log(window.onkeydown)}, 1000);
```

The javascript console will print the "window.onkeydown" function, if this function wasn't override, the console will show "null" values. If you use any UI library that override window.onkeydown, you'll identify on this console what event was overriding this callback.

In my case, we're using modal components with angular and bootstrap. When we show the modal, from 3rd party library change the "window.onkeydown" event and blocks some keys to be forwarded to my screen.